# managing firebase real-time database using http or databaseReference more efficient?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

is it more efficient managing the database on flutter using http or databaseReference 
i just use http right now on flutter and i tried databaseReference Previously on java i think http is easier but i don't care which easier as long it gives me the best performance

http

```
 http.post('https://flutter-course-36df8.firebaseio.com/' + 'products.josn',
```

databaseReference

```
final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
void getData(){
  databaseReference.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    print('Data : ${snapshot.value}');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the api provided by firebase, it is much better. For example `FirebaseDatabase.instance` will retrieve the root node in the Firebase Database which is better than adding the url.

Also using `databaseReference` you can retrieve data `once` or on every change on the database.